# Will D3DImage + Media Foundation (EVR) provide better performance comparing to D3DImage + DirectShow (VMR9)?

Tags: wpf, video, media-player, directshow, ms-media-foundation

I am developing video app using WPF and DirectShow. Capability of providing an overlay over the playback area was achieved with D3DImage and custom allocator-presenter, as a result I have high CPU loading (80% at 20 streams with fps = 2). Will D3DImage +  Media Foundation (EVR) provide better performance comparing to D3DImage + DirectShow (VMR9)?

Comment: What type of videos do you have? Which codec? Because High CPU load means the videos decoding is not hardware accellerated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, EVR could be used both with DirectShow and MediaFoundation.
Here is a very good example project which combines WPF D3DImage, DirectShow and EVR: https://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com.
It is even possible to toggle between EVR and VMR9 renderer in wpfmediakit and compare CPU usage.

In general, EVR is the best choice for Vista or later. Here is a simple [guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374574(v=vs.85).aspx) for picking best DirectShow video renderer.